# EF Core linq and conditional include and theninclude problem

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having a problem with getting a result when trying to get objects with multiple levels.
This is what I am trying to do roughly:

```
_context.Investors.Where(s => s.Id == userId)
    .Include(c => c.Coins) //only want this if some kind of flag is given by the user.
    .ThenInclude(ct => ct.CoinType)
    .Include(c => c.Bricks) //only want this if some kind of flag is given by the user.
```

Essentially I am getting a lot of flags indicating if I should include parts of the object.
I got it almost to work. Like this:

```
_context.Investors.Where(s => s.Id == userId)
    .Select(i => new
    {
        i,
        Bricks = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.Bricks) != GapiInvestorFlags.Bricks ? null : i.Bricks,
        Offers = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.Offers) != GapiInvestorFlags.Offers ? null : i.Offers,
        Coins = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.Coins) != GapiInvestorFlags.Coins ? null : i.Coins,
        CoinTransactions = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.CoinTransactions) != GapiInvestorFlags.CoinTransactions ? null : i.CoinTransactions,
        OfferTransactions = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.OfferTransactions) != GapiInvestorFlags.OfferTransactions ? null : i.OfferTransactions,
        BuyTransactions = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.BuyTransactions) != GapiInvestorFlags.BuyTransactions ? null : i.BuyTransactions,
        SellTransactions = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.SellTransactions) != GapiInvestorFlags.SellTransactions ? null : i.SellTransactions
    }).AsEnumerable()
    .Select(e => e.i).FirstOrDefault();
```

This works except that the Coins section also has a cointype in it so I need to include it too. But when I add my code, the whole section stops working.

This is what I tried:

```
_context.Investors.Where(s => s.Id == userId)
    .Include(c => c.Coins)
    .ThenInclude(ct => ct.CoinType)
    .Select(i => new
    {
        i,
        Bricks = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.Bricks) != GapiInvestorFlags.Bricks ? null : i.Bricks,
        Offers = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.Offers) != GapiInvestorFlags.Offers ? null : i.Offers,
        Coins = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.Coins) != GapiInvestorFlags.Coins ? null : i.Coins.Select(c => new { c, c.CoinType }).ToList(),
        CoinTransactions = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.CoinTransactions) != GapiInvestorFlags.CoinTransactions ? null : i.CoinTransactions,
        OfferTransactions = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.OfferTransactions) != GapiInvestorFlags.OfferTransactions ? null : i.OfferTransactions,
        BuyTransactions = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.BuyTransactions) != GapiInvestorFlags.BuyTransactions ? null : i.BuyTransactions,
        SellTransactions = (details & GapiInvestorFlags.SellTransactions) != GapiInvestorFlags.SellTransactions ? null : i.SellTransactions
    }).AsEnumerable()
    .Select(e => e.i).FirstOrDefault();
```

I really can't tell why it does not work.

Basically when I change:

```
i.Coins
```

To

```
i.Coins.Select(c => new { c, c.CoinType }).ToList()
```

it stops working.

Comment: _Essentially I am getting **a lot of flags** indicating if I should include parts of the object_ - looks like your query doing to much, consider having different queries for the flags

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The technique you are using is not really explicit loading (`Include` / `ThenInclude`), but trick based on projection and EF Core navigation property fix-up, so I can't say why it stops working. EF Core still processes projections and includes differently, so it might be a defect in the current processing.

Implementing conditional include at the root query level is relatively easy. Note that the `Include` method starts from (is defined for) `IQueryable<TEntity>` and the returned `IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty>>` is also `IQueryable<TEntity>`. Which means you can keep `IQueryable<T>` query variable and apply conditional transformations similar to chained `Where` operators.

To make that easier, you could create a custom helper extension method like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> If<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    bool condition,
    Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> transform
)
{ 
    return condition? transform(source) : source;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
_context.Investors.Where(s => s.Id == userId)
    .If(flagCoins, q => q.Include(e => e.Coins)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.CoinType))
    .If(flagBricks, q => q.Include(e => e.Bricks))
```

If you need something similar for the nested levels (`ThenInclude`), then add the following 2 extension methods:

```
public static IQueryable<T> If<T, P>(
    this IIncludableQueryable<T, P> source,
    bool condition,
    Func<IIncludableQueryable<T, P>, IQueryable<T>> transform
)
    where T : class
{
    return condition ? transform(source) : source;
}

public static IQueryable<T> If<T, P>(
    this IIncludableQueryable<T, IEnumerable<P>> source,
    bool condition,
    Func<IIncludableQueryable<T, IEnumerable<P>>, IQueryable<T>> transform
)
    where T : class
{
    return condition ? transform(source) : source;
}
```

which will allow you to use something like this:

```
_context.Investors.Where(s => s.Id == userId)
    .If(flagCoins, q => q.Include(e => e.Coins)
        .If(flagCoinType, q2 => q2.ThenInclude(e => e.CoinType)))
    .If(flagBricks, q => q.Include(e => e.Bricks))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this is so much better than what I was doing.

Comment: Slick implementation. Works perfectly.

Comment: This is great, but why isn't this built into EF core?

Comment: Is it possible to have this condition work like a `.Where(x => x.something != thisthing)` condition?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Nope, this is just a compact way to conditionally include related data when *building* the query. Hence the conditions can be based only on some parameters which can be evaluated at the time of calling the methods.

Comment: This is a nice example. I was wondering if it is possible to use that solution where the condition is based in some attributes of the main object. For example flagCoins dependes of Investor attribute.

Comment: @JoseLuisSuarezCabrera Unfortunately no, since all this is happening at query building time where we have no access to the attributes of the main object (there are no objects at all at that time). The only supported by EFC is filtered include, but it is for filtering the "included" items, not to eliminate include itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use my extension method.

1. Using:

```cs
 var filteredTransactions = _transactionRepository.GetAll()
                    .Where(x => x.CreationTime.Ticks <= input.FetchingTikes)
                    .IncludeIf(input.Filter.IsNotNullOrWhitespace(), t => t.DestinationAccountFk.Merchant, t => t.SourceAccountFk.UserFk)
```

2. Extenstion:

```cs
 public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeIf<TEntity>([NotNull] this 
   IQueryable<TEntity> source
                ,bool condition
                ,params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] 
    navigationPropertyPaths)
                where TEntity : class
            {
                if (condition)
                {
                    if (navigationPropertyPaths.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
                    {
                        foreach (var navigationPropertyPath in 
   navigationPropertyPaths)
                        {
                            source = source.Include(navigationPropertyPath);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return source;
            }
```

3. Other extensions:

```cs
        public static bool IsNotNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            if (list.IsNotNull() && list.IsNotEmpty())
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static bool IsNotNull(this object obj)
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static bool IsNotEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            if (list.Count() > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: nice one, but do you really need empty checks? simple `!=null` on params array should be ok.  The other extensions are excessive I think

Comment: How about Empty check?

Comment: you don't need to check if enumerable is empty, foreach loop only needs a not null enumerable