# ThenInclude with conditions based on Parent entity on EF Core 8

Tags: entity-framework-core

Let's see these entities (tables in SQL Server)

- Project (has many)
- Milestone (has many)
- Task (has many)
- SubTask

`Project` entity has a `Type` attribute. Type can be A, B.

`Task` entity has a `Gender` attribute. Gender can be X, Y, One, Two.

`Type` attribute in `Project` should allow only these combinations:

- Projects marked with Type A only allows Tasks with Gender X or Y.
- Projects marked with Type B only allows Tasks with Gender One or Two.

Well, our solution allowed different all kind of combinations until now. So I am working on EF Core 8 to apply that kind of filtering and ignore the old values.

I am using this query to get all projects with milestones, tasks and subtasks.

```
query
    .Include(p => p.Milestones)
        .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Tasks)
        .ThenInclude(pa => pa.SubTasks)
    .AsSplitQuery();
```

but how can I do to get all projects A with only task with Gender X and Y and projects B with only One and Two?

I have tried to use If from this post : [EF Core linq and conditional include and theninclude problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474431/ef-core-linq-and-conditional-include-and-theninclude-problem)

Also, I tried using EF Plus with `IncludeIf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read [here, under "The filter expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core/61147681#61147681), the expression in `(Then)Include` must be "stand-alone", i.e. it can't use range variables that are used before the includes.

In your case it should be something like this:

```cs
query
    .Include(p => p.Milestones)
        .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Tasks
            .Where(t => 
                (t.Milestone.Project.Type == "A"
                    && (t.Gender == "X" || t.Gender == "Y"))
             || (t.Milestone.Project.Type == "B"
                    && (t.Gender == "One" || t.Gender == "Two"))))
        .ThenInclude(pa => pa.SubTasks)
    .AsSplitQuery();
```

This requires back-references from `Task` to `Milestone` to `Project`. It's not elegant, but necessary because you can't use `p.Type` in the predicate.